# Get the message ID in the survey monkey response

Tags: surveymonkey

I am using survey monkey v3 API's to send survey emails. While sending a survey email from one collector, I am sending two different survey messages for the same recipient. However, while collecting the survey responses from survey monkey using the api "/surveys/{id}/responses/bulk", I couldn't find the messageID in it. So I how can I find which response belong to which  message of the collector then? Is there a different API that I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

What's the use case for tracking the specific message? You have the `recipient_id`, and first/last/email fields.

You can get recipient details at `/collectors/{collector_id}/recipients/{recipient_id}`. There's no way (as far as I can tell) to query for this other than searching your messages with `/collectors/{collector_id}/messages/{message_id}/recipients`

Generally speaking, when you add recipients to a message, they are shared with the collector. Which specific message was responded to is not really tracked, the tracking ID is the `recipient_id` with respect to the collector.

If you are interested in message stats (ex. which message gets a better response rate) you can use the [message stats endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-stats).

With regards to having a different message for say different products, unfortunately the message ID is not tied to a response, but two options are:

1) Use a different collector for each product (not ideal if there is a lot)
2) Use extra fields on the recipient (see example):

Example:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id1>/recipients
{
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Tester",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "extra_fields": {
        "product": "shoes"
    }
}

POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id2>/recipients
{
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Tester",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "extra_fields": {
        "product": "shirts"
    }
}
```

Then when you fetch the responses, you'll get that information in metadata, example:

```
{
  "id": "<response_id>",
  "recipient_id": "<recipient_id>",
  "collector_id": "<collector_id>",
  ...
  "metadata": {
    "contact": {
      "product": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "shoes"
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "test@example.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing to watch out for is that the extra fields from the contact do not currently show up in the `/responses/bulk` endpoint, only individual `responses/<id>` endpoint. Also with extra fields you can't filter responses where `product=shoes` or whatnot. Those are some limitations with the current API - but hopefully it can at least be helpful for now.

Comment: If you believe that different messages are impacting response rates, you can fetch that info from https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-stats.

Comment: @General Kandalaft: Here is one of the use case. Some of my customers buy two products on the same day. If I have to send a survey invitation for both the products to same the recipient, I have to create two different survey invitation messages and send them. So there will be two messageID's. After the recipient completes his survey's, we need to know the response given for each product. So, now how do we know which response is given for which message? Survey monkey has to send the messageID as well in return. I think, survey monkey missed that part.

Comment: @Bobby I added an edit with more information that may be helpful to you